# Accents don't render correctly in email send by PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email

All accents (
é, à, etc) are rendered as weird characters in emails sent by PHP `mail()` function. Here's the code generating this email:

```
$email_message = '<html><body>';
$email_message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #aaa;" cellpadding="10">';       
$email_message .= "<tr><td style='background: #eee;'><strong>FIRST NAME:</strong> </td><td>" . $form_first_name . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td style='background: #eee;'><strong>LAST NAME:</strong> </td><td>" . $form_last_name . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr><td style='background: #eee;'><strong>MESSAGE:</strong> </td><td>" . $form_message . "</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "</table>";
$email_message .= "</body></html>";
$email_message = nl2br( $email_message ); 
$sender = $form_email;                  
$reply_to = $form_email; 
$email_headers = "From: " . strip_tags( $form_email ) . "\r\n";
$email_headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags( $form_email ) . "\r\n";
$email_headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$email_headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";  
$email_message = stripslashes( $email_message );
$result_mail_function = mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $email_headers );
```

Why accent don't render properly?

Comment: try replace  "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n" with  'Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8'

Comment: Worked well, thanks :)